# How to configure cookie authentication expiration on Cloudant?

Tags: couchdb, session-cookies, cloudant

Using [cookie authentication](https://docs.cloudant.com/api/authn.html) on Cloudant, is is possible to adjust the life of the cookie?

On a normal CouchDB setup "the [session timeout](http://wiki.apache.org/couchdb/Session_API) is specified by the "timeout" parameter in the "couch_httpd_auth" section of the configuration. If not specified it defaults to 600 seconds (10 minutes)." I haven't found this option in the Cloudant dashboard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The lifespan of a cookie is not configurable by the user in Cloudant. Cookies timeout after 24 hours.